# Django Upload button in Bootstrap href without JS

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, django-forms

Is there a way to insert a Django FileInput form field in bootstrap href link without using JS.
I have something like this:

```
   <div class="post-new-tab-nav">
                                        
          <a href="{{ form.viPicture }}" uk-tooltip="title:Close"> <i class="uil-image"></i> </a>
          <a href="#"> <i class="uil-user-plus"></i> </a>
          <a href="#"> <i class="uil-video"></i> </a>
                                       
  </div>
```

The form field that I am trying to insert would be {{ form.viPicture }}. What I intend to achieve would be to trigger the file upload once the href is clicked.

Can this be done without using JS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you didn't say which methods you had tried, here is my suggestion: take a look at the [official docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/file-uploads/#file-uploads). You just need to apply some changes to your form and view and everything will be there, rendered without custom Javascript.